# How to find out the Icon Badge count?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, badge

I'm using push notifications on my iOS app and everything is working great.

The icon badge is working and when I open the app I clear it with this code:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
```

But before clearing it I would like to find out what is the badge count to make some changes on the app according to the number of notifications the user has when opening the app.

Is it possible to do get this number?

Thanks!

Comment: Just call [[UIApplication sharedApplication] badgeNumber]; before you set it to 0.

Comment: Thanks! The right code is applicationIconBadgeNumber. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber
```

Try

Comment: Awesome! This works:     badgeCount = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber];